# when setting .eval() my model performs worse than when I set .train()

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, eval

During the training phase, I select the model parameters with the best performance metric.

```
if performance_metric.item()>max_performance:
        max_performance= performance_metric.item()
        torch.save(neural_net.state_dict(), PATH+'/best_model.pt')
```

This is the neural network model used:

```
class Neural_Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, M,shape_input,batch_size):
            super(Neural_Net, self).__init__()
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(shape_input,M)
            #self.dense1 = nn.Linear(shape_input,M)
            self.dense1 = nn.Linear(M,M) #Used with the LSTM
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.dense1.weight)
            self.dense2 = nn.Linear(M,M)
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.dense2.weight)
            self.dense3 = nn.Linear(M,1)
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.dense3.weight)
            self.drop   = nn.Dropout(0.7)
            self.bachnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(M)
            self.relu = nn.ReLU()
            self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
            
            self.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1,batch_size,M),torch.zeros(1,batch_size,M))
            
        def forward(self, x):
            lstm_out, self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(x.view(1 ,len(x), -1), self.hidden_cell)
            x = self.drop(self.relu(self.dense1(self.bachnorm1(lstm_out.view(len(x), -1)))))
            x = self.drop(self.relu(self.dense2(x)))
            x = self.relu(self.dense3(x))
            return x
```

After that I load the model with the best parameters and set the evaluation mode:

```
neural_net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH+'/best_model.pt'))
neural_net.eval()
```

The results are completely random. When I set `train()` the performance is similar to the selected best model parameter.

There is an important aspect of the eval() that I am forgetting? Is the batch normalization correctly used? I am using a batch the same size as in the training phase for the test phase.

Comment: Try using `.eval()` on your **training data** and see if the result is similar to when you use `.train()` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your batch size, training/test dataset size, or the training/test dataset discrepancies, this issue has been discussed on the pytorch forums previously [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/model-eval-gives-incorrect-loss-for-model-with-batchnorm-layers/7561/41).

In my experience, it sounds very much like your latent training data representation in your model is significantly different to your validation data representation. The main advice I can provide is for you to try reducing the momentum of your batchnorm layer. It might be worth substituting a layernorm layer instead (which doesn't track a running mean/standard deviation) OR setting `track_running_stats=False` in the batchnorm1d function and seeing if the problem persists.